# Setting home page in a SPA application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, durandal

Hi I am working on a SPA application using the Hot Towel template and asp.net MVC.My applications home page is curently set to point to the Home and Index controller in RouteConfig.cs.

I have to change that route to point to a Durandel view.

This link should be the one that opens my homepage:

```
http://localhost:61620/Home/MyCourses#/dashboard
```

If it was asp.net mvc I would set it in RouteConfig.cs.If that is still the case how can I do that?If not where should I set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, in a Durandal-based SPA, there is code in the shell's activate function that uses the router to activate the "home" page.  In a Hot Towel template, this code is in the shell's `boot()` function.  This code normally looks like this:

```
    function activate() {
        return boot();
    }

    function boot() {
        ... //router setup
        return router.activate('home');
    }
```

This sets up the app so that, when the user browses to `http://localhost:61620/Home/MyCourses#/`, the app will load the `dashboard` route automatically, even though it may not be part of the literal url.